# Find all functions such that:$ \int_0^1 g(x)f(x)~dx =\int_0^1f^2(x)~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-equations

I am looking to solve this integral problem.

> Find all functions such that:$$ \int_0^1 g(x)f(x)~dx =\int_0^1f^2(x)~dx$$

I found a trivial space of solutions and that is $g(x)=f(x).$ Are there any other solutions? Looking for different kinds of examples of $f$ and $g$ for which it's true.

Comment: Do you want $g$ such that it's true for all $f$? or, $f$ such that it's true for all $g$? or, just all examples of $f$ and $g$ for which it's true?

Comment: E.g., for $f$ identically zero, it's true for all $g$.

Comment: I suggest that you reformulate the question as follows. Given $f$ strictly positive and in L2. Is $g=f$ the only solution in L2 of the equation...

Comment: @GerryMyerson examples of $f$ and $g$ for which it's true

Comment: Surely, for arbitrary $f$, you can find an uncountable infinity of functions $g$ for which the equation holds. I don't think there is anything interesting to say about them, in general.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for different $f$ and $g$ for which it's true. The answer below gives one class of examples

Comment: Alternatively, we may consider $f(x)=g(x)$ _almost everywhere_ in $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Fourier type approach.

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable set. Given $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $\|f\|_\Omega \neq 0$ (otherwise the problem is trivial) consider any $g_*\in L^2(\Omega)$ not orthogonal to $f$, i.e., such that $(f,g_*)_\Omega\neq 0$.

Then take
$$
g=\frac{\|f\|_\Omega^2}{(f,g_*)_\Omega} g_*
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many possibilities. Rewrite the equation as $$\int_0^1f(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx=0$$
Then the following are possible solutions: if $$\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$$any $g(x)=f(x)+C, C\in\mathbb R$ verifies the equation. Here are some examples:

1. $f(x)=x-\frac12$, $g(x)=x+\frac12$
2. $f(x)=\cos(2\pi x)$, $g(x)=\cos(2\pi x)+1=2\cos^2(\pi x)$